# All Unit test does not work in first attempt

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have 70 unit tests and wrote them using Microsoft unit test framework. I am experiencing strange behavior. If I press button to run all tests then few of them does not work every time in first try.

However when I press run failed tests then all failed tests worked. If I run in debug mode then all tests again work properly. I am using VS 2013 and Microsoft unit test framework. Am I missing something or is something wrong with configuration. I am using right deployment item attributes in test methods.

Comment: Do you have some async code in your tests?

Comment: no, I do not have async code, however, I have deployment items and if re-build my project and run these failed test individually then these tests work and do not show any issue

Comment: typically this happens when you depends on some static property in your tests. Static property can makes the test dependent on other tests. Can you provide sample of failing test?

Comment: I have static properties in few classes. Its difficult for me to share code because of several reasons. Thanks for a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue and the only way to solve it was using the DeploymentItem in the testsettings file. Using the deployment item attribute for testmethods did not work properly, especially when using different testrunners (like VS and Resharper testrunner). I'd advice you to move all your deployment items defined for the testmethods to your testsettings file.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that I was specifying the deployment file name above test class. Due to which test methods were not working. Its my guess. However, I am copying deployment files manually using reflection.